# Is there a way to set a clipping rectangle when drawing a bitmap?

Tags: android, android-canvas, android-bitmap

I'm trying to write a program that will have a rectangle that can be moved around.  Inside this rectangle will be a bitmap.

Is there a way to set a clipping rectangle for the bitmap, so just the portion within the rectangle will be drawn?

Is there a way to set a clipping rectangle when you draw a bitmap? I did not see a method for it.

Answer (score 0):

Use [Canvas.drawBitmap()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Canvas.html#drawBitmap%28android.graphics.Bitmap,%20android.graphics.Rect,%20android.graphics.Rect,%20android.graphics.Paint%29), passing the "src" Rect indicating the part of the bitmap that you need to draw.

Answer (score 0):

Override the onDraw method and just before drawing your bitmap, use one of the `clipRect` methods below to set clipping rectangle.

> `boolean clipRect(Rect rect, Region.Op op)`
>
> Modify the current clip with the specified rectangle, which is expressed in local coordinates.
>
> `boolean clipRect(RectF rect, Region.Op op)`
>
> Modify the current clip  with the specified rectangle.
>
> `boolean clipRect(int left, int top, int right, int bottom)`
>
> Intersect the current clip with the specified rectangle, which is expressed in local coordinates.
>
> `boolean clipRect(float left, float top, float right, float bottom)`
>
> Intersect the current clip with the specified rectangle, which is expressed in
>   local coordinates.
>
> `boolean clipRect(RectF rect)`
>
> Intersect the current clip with the specified rectangle, which is expressed in local coordinates.
>
> `boolean clipRect(float left, float top, float right, float bottom, Region.Op op)`
>
> Modify the current clip with the specified rectangle, which is expressed in local coordinates.
>
> `boolean clipRect(Rect rect)`
>
> Intersect the current clip with the specified rectangle, which is expressed in local coordinates.

*from [http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Canvas.html](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Canvas.html_)*